# Creating such an Android UI

Tags: java, android, user-interface

[image]
I am attempting to create an Android UI similar to the one shown above.
This type of layout is fairly common in websites and I want to recreate this for my Android app.

It is a list of names and when you click on a name it expands and displays some customized UI.

Can someone please guide me on how this can be achieved ?
To be specific, the expansion when clicking a name so that a new `View` is displayed.

Comment: You can have a simpel ListView and every second view from your listview will be "collapsed", but when you click on a particular item, the element (item+1) would expand

Comment: @MocialovBoris so I must have a custom `ExpandableListViewAdapter` ? :)

Comment: Implement your own BaseAdapter, Google it and you find how to implement it

Comment: @LittleChild yes, or simply start with ListView and make your own ExpandableListView with custom adapter

Comment: or if you are looking for an easy implementation, then http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [ExpandableListItemAdapter](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/blob/master/example/src/com/haarman/listviewanimations/ExpandableListItemActivity.java) class in the [ListViewAnimations library](http://nhaarman.github.io/ListViewAnimations).

You can seperately specify a header `View` and a content `View`. The content view smoothly animates in to sight when clicked.

Comment: I am having a hard time creating the views. I can create views by extending `BaseExpandableListAdapter` and using its methods. I am stuck with your adapter.
I just don't know which child's data to supply in `getChildView` as I just can not identify which title (group) is being referred to.
Any work around ? [This is my reference](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/)

Comment: When you extend `ExpandableListItemAdapter` from the ListViewAnimations library, you need to override two methods: `getTitleView()`,  and `getContentView()`. In both methods, you get the same `position`, with which you can retrieve your data `Object` to show in the Views.

Comment: Sure, that is not a problem. The problem is when a title has multiple child views in which case I am unable to determine which title a child belongs to :)

Comment: That just would be one `ViewGroup` containing the multiple child `Views`s?

Comment: Yes, that would be it :)

Comment: Dude, although I have your jar file and `NineOldAndroid` in my lib, I get a class not found <com.nineold.> from <com.haarman.> What is going wrong ?

Comment: @LittleChild be sure to export "Android Private Libraries" on your project.

Comment: `08-08 19:36:13.050: E/dalvikvm(27827): Could not find class 'com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator[]', referenced from method com.haarman.listviewanimations.swinginadapters.prepared.AlphaInAnimationAdapter.getAnimators`

Comment: I have it in my build path now. Yet, I get that

Comment: Uhm... any solution to that, mate ? :)

Answer (score 1):

I have done something very similar, you can use the [code provided here](https://github.com/Udinic/SmallExamples/tree/master/ExpandAnimationExample) (check src/com/udinic/expand_animation_example/ExpandAnimation.java) to achieve exactly what you are looking for.

**Sample code:**

```
final int animationTime=250;
ExpandAnimation expandAni = new ExpandAnimation(expandingView, animationTime);
expandingView.startAnimation(expandAni);
```

Note that the code would call requestLayout() to perform the animation which is computationally expensive. So if you are trying to apply this animation to a complex LinearLayout encapsulated in a ScrollView, the result would be choppy. In this case try to use ListView to populate the screen instead.

Comment: Will definitely work on this and get back to you :)